# Cookies saved using document.cookie getting deleted after closing the browser

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie, autologin

Using the common code for setting the username and password in cookie via javascript as below -

```
function submitLogin(){
        var uNameInCookie=checkCookie("username");

        var passInCookie=checkCookie("password");

        if(uNameInCookie!=="" && passInCookie!=""){
            document.loginForm.login.value=uNameInCookie;
            document.loginForm.passwd.value=passInCookie;
            document.loginForm.submit();
        }
        else{
            if(checkInput()){

            document.loginForm.submit();

            }
        }
}
    function checkCookie(property){

    var x= property;
    var prop = getCookie(x);
    return prop;
}

function getCookie(cName){
var name = cName + "=";
var cookiez = document.cookie.split(';');

for ( var i=0;i<cookiez.length;i++){

        var c= cookiez[i].trim();
        if(c.indexOf(name)==0){

                        return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }

        }

        return ""
}

function checkInput()
    {

          if (document.loginForm.login.value == "")
          {

              return false;
          }
          else if (document.loginForm.passwd.value == "")
          {

              return false;
          }
          if (document.loginForm.login.value!= "" && document.loginForm.login.value!=null) 
          {
          var usernameValue=document.loginForm.login.value;

          setCookie("username",usernameValue,365);
          }
          if (document.loginForm.passwd.value!= "" && document.loginForm.passwd.value!=null)
          {
          var passwordValue=document.loginForm.passwd.value;

          setCookie("password",passwordValue,365);
          }
          return true;
}  
function setCookie ( cName, cValue, expDays){

        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (expDays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expDate = d.toGMTString();
        alert(expDate);
        document.cookie = cName + "=" + cValue + ";" + expDate + ";path=/";

    }
    window.onload=submitLogin();
</script>
```

the browser is able to auto login the details and submit the form only when I do a logout.

But if I close the browser and hit the url ,the username and password stored in cookie is gone and the form does not auto login.

Is there anything wrong with the  code or is it some kind of browser setting. I have added the specific site also to add cookies if needed. Is there anything else that we need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running the application in an anonymous browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is when you are setting the cookie it's expiration date is not set and it's taking cookie for **Session** scope. Make correct the following line:

```
document.cookie = cName + "=" + cValue + "; expires=" + expDate + ";path=/";
```

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot Deepak, you correctly pointed out the mistake. This was the first question I posted on Stack. And was eagerly awaiting an answer.